# Does setName function (AS 3.0) alter XML file?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am quite new to dealing with xml files through Flash and Action Script 3.0.
I write this piece of code with the intention of changing all the QUESTION children into WRONG.

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("question.xml");
        var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_complete, false, 0, true);
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);


    private function urlLoader_complete(e:Event):void {
        var question:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
        question.QUESTION.setName("WRONG");
        trace("FINISH!");
    }
```

The program runs and I successfully got the word Finish traced. However when I check the xml file question.xml, not one of the QUESTION children is renamed.

Can someone explain this for me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setName` is the correct method, but in your example, you are not using it on the individual nodes, but on the XMLList that is returned by `question.QUESTION` - which, technically, does not appear in the XML tree, and therefore does not reflect the change within the XML output.

You need to iterate over the actual nodes to get a result:

```
var question:XML = <QUESTIONS><QUESTION /><QUESTION /></QUESTIONS>;
var questions:XMLList = question.QUESTION;
for each( var node:XML in questions )
    node.setName( "WRONG" );
trace ( question ); // output: <QUESTIONS><WRONG /><WRONG /></QUESTIONS>
```

Or for a single node:

```
var question:XML = <QUESTIONS><QUESTION /></QUESTIONS>;
var questions:XMLList = question.QUESTION;
questions[0].setName( "WRONG" );
trace ( question ); // output: <QUESTIONS><WRONG /></QUESTIONS>
```

Comment: Is this also applied if my XML list has exactly 1 QUESTION node? I thought if it has only one node of the name you can directly use it like that. And what if I only want to change one node only? Thanks

Comment: It works the same way when there's only one QUESTION in the list.  If you want to change a specific node, you can apply the method directly by specifying the index of that node: `question.QUESTION[0].setName("WRONG")`.

Comment: I still cannot get it right. Firstly I make sure that there is only one child named QUESTION then I use the original code. After that I change it to `question.QUESTION[0].setName("WRONG")` but nothing changes. One interesting thing is that when I use trace(question.children()) the WRONG child appears but in the XML file that is stored in the hard disc, it is still QUESTION

Comment: I've added an example for a single changed node, and included simple XML data in the code snippet - try this, then see where else in your code the error may be.

Comment: Sorry I think I have misled you. After experimenting for a while I have managed to see that if the xml is purely within the application itself then my code has achieved its purpose. But if I want to change a real xml file that is placed in the same folder as the source files then I fail. I think that, basically, I have only changed the question variable, not the file that is loaded into it. My question therefore should be how to change the file that is loaded into your variable. I have edited my question. Sorry for all this inconveniences.

Comment: Np.  I would suggest you make it a new question, though, or unaccept my answer - the way it is now, the question appears as solved.

Comment: I will reverse the question back then. Thanks for the help. As for the new question, now I have fully understood it, I think I will find out more before asking